# How to send email with template with sendgrid in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, email, sendgrid

send.js

I tested the mail, but its a hard content.I want to attach a dynamic content

```
    const msg = {
            to: email,
            from: 'no-reply@mail.com',
            subject: 'subject',
            html: '<strong>and easy to do anywhere, even with Node.js</strong>',
        };
        sgMail
            .send(msg)
            .then(() => {
                console.log('sended');
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log('error', error);
            });
```

Template.js

```
module.exports = (data)=> {
  return `
    <html>
      <body>
        <div style="text-align: center;">
          <h3>I'd like your input!</h3>
          <p>Please answer the following question:</p>
          <p>${data.body}</p>
        </div>
      </body>
    </html>
  `;
};
```

Would there be any way to attach html templates
please help me

Answer (score 0):

Hi Rajendran ,
              I have tested the below solution and its works fine using createReadStream() the formatString will contain your html.

```
const sendEmail = (body) => {
let formatString;
fs.open('template.html', 'r', (err, fd) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
    if (err.code === 'ENOENT') {
      console.error('myfile does not exist');
      return;
    }
    throw err;
  }

  const rr = fs.createReadStream('template.html');
  rr.on('readable', () => {
    const result = `${rr.read()}`;
    formatString = result.replace('####', body);
    console.log(formatString);
  });
  rr.on('end', () => {
    console.log('end');
  });
});
return formatString;
```

};

```
<html>
<body>
  <div style="text-align: center;">
    <h3>I'd like your input!</h3>
    <p>Please answer the following question:</p>
    <p>####</p>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: But I want send template with dynamic content, So I need to pass  content from send.js to template.js

Comment: yes you can using sendEmail function i have attached html also

Comment: `const msg = {
    to: email,
    from: 'no-reply@mail.com',
    subject:
     'subject',
    html: sendEmail,
   };`          Is this correct, but i recieved a error msg from sendgrid callback

Comment: try like this const msg = { to: email, from: 'no-reply@mail.com', subject: 'subject', html: sendEmail (data.body)};